# JavaScript RegExp Capturing Groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I need extract some information from `test string` using **"(\w)\w"** pattern with RegExp in JavaScript. I want to get all results with capturing groups. For example: **"(t)e","(e)s","(s)t"** and so on. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the values in all capturing groups, you can get those matching using 2 capturing groups inside a positive lookahead.

The value of `te` is in capture group 1, the value of `t` in group 2. The first value in the array is empty, as the pattern itself only matches a position.

```
(?=((\w)\w))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBBNiF/1)

```js
const regex = /(?=((\w)\w))/g;
let s = "test string";
console.log([...s.matchAll(regex)]);
```

If you use a single capturing group `(?=(\w\w))` you will have the values `te`, `es`, `st` etc... in group 1.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nRStkp/1)